# WxPython exit code 1073740940

Tags: python, python-3.x, error-handling, wxpython, exit-code

I build a project with wxpython that also include multi-threading and sockets.
Sometimes when I ran the project, the run is stopped and i get a strange exit code such as 
"Process finished with exit code -1073740940 (0xC0000374)"
After research I found that this line makes it happen -                 messageTxt.CharRight()
Someone knows why?

Comment: Show more code. Don't be shy! xD. When you uses multithreading you must call UI with wx.CallAfter or similar. Are you doing well?

Comment: It is a very long code. what are you meaning in wx.CallAfter? can you give me an example or something.

Comment: Sure! There are thousands of examples.
https://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/05/22/wxpython-and-threads/